# Additional fields from facebook and google authentication within ASP.NET Core MVC 2.2

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, google-authentication, facebook-authentication, asp.net-core-2.2

I develop a web application with ASP.NET Core MVC 2.2 and I want to get some more information from the user by facebook and google authentication/login.

Actually the authentication via facebook and google works, but just give me some information about the name of the user. I need the date of birth and the user profile image. How can I do this?

When I try to do the facebook authentication, I will redirected to following URL: https://www.facebook.com/v3.1/dialog/oauth?client_id=2255814967787552&scope=email,https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Fdialog%2Foauth&response_type=code&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A44381%2Fsignin-facebook&state=CfDJ8D6zBetw7iFAjlSqmbgb4YDXGCqkP9eC0ywTHzwmmZ_KjSgwprhdP-TuZpZheevTP90ZlwtBXWr1DkVvsOJe842onEdxPxNMFuEz0yg8HtFZSvQwfFOT4E46EHkM7s0xWPh_VwFy6BQVvtDL7BrtBtTssvAuu7zdCcX7kgLAb6YWuAQUUSx6ocbcRwQVKd-Gg9bwBVmtyVQfFXVLJAMkbTEMsR4ajeibSM558iggvPIzct-SYu-hOu474PFDMmG9iB9JNkSytsXSRltjSrIT0clmbrahqQbmLL8Pa-IM33Gl

When I try to do the google authentication, it works, but there is no claim type within the external login info principal..

And I don't know how to get the user profile image..

My startup:

```
services.AddAuthentication()
    .AddFacebook(facebookOptions =>
        {
            facebookOptions.AppId = Configuration["Authentication:Facebook:AppId"];
            facebookOptions.AppSecret = Configuration["Authentication:Facebook:AppSecret"];
            facebookOptions.Scope.Add("https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth");
            facebookOptions.Fields.Add(ClaimTypes.GivenName);
            facebookOptions.Fields.Add(ClaimTypes.Surname);
            facebookOptions.Fields.Add(ClaimTypes.DateOfBirth);
            facebookOptions.ClaimActions.MapJsonKey(ClaimTypes.GivenName, "givenname");
            facebookOptions.ClaimActions.MapJsonKey(ClaimTypes.Surname, "surname");
            facebookOptions.ClaimActions.MapJsonKey(ClaimTypes.DateOfBirth, "dateofbirth");
        })
    .AddGoogle(googleOptions =>
        {
            googleOptions.ClientId = Configuration["Authentication:Google:ClientId"];
            googleOptions.ClientSecret = Configuration["Authentication:Google:ClientSecret"];
            googleOptions.Scope.Add("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login");
            googleOptions.ClaimActions.MapJsonKey(ClaimTypes.GivenName, "givenname");
            googleOptions.ClaimActions.MapJsonKey(ClaimTypes.Surname, "surname");
            googleOptions.ClaimActions.MapJsonKey(ClaimTypes.DateOfBirth, "dateofbirth");
        });
```

Comment: You need to request additional scopes and/or use the auth token to manually request the required information from the respective APIs. Email should be universally available via a particular scope; you'll need to consult the respective documentation of each service to determine the exact scope required. Birthday may or may not be available as a scope, and may not even be available via an API requests, depending on the user's privacy settings, since it's technically PII. Something like a profile picture is generally going to require a secondary API request. It just depends.

Comment: In general, consult the API documentation for each service. The auth integration in ASP.NET Core is not comprehensive API integration. It's just OAuth/OIDC and any information you can possible get through that flow via scopes.

Answer (score 1):

The scope required for birthdate, is: `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/user.birthday.read`. You may refer to Google Documentation [Here](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/googlescopes) to get a list of any oauth2 scope needed for all google api's.

However please note that in order to get birthdate's info, you'll need to manually make an authorized request (that is: including a baerer token which has the reqiured scope in the authorization header) to Google People API as documented [Here](https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/people/get). That's because the current implementation in AspNetCore for GoogleAuth fetches its authentication claims from google UserInfo endpoint (https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v2/userinfo), which does not provide birthday info at all, even for an authorized request, so just adding the birthday scope to `GoogleOptions.Scope` in the `AddGoogle(...)` method while configuring the google authentication for your app, still wont retrieve for you the birthday.